# Node cannot upgrade on High Sierra

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

Mac OS High Sierra here. I'm trying to upgrade from `node` 10.4.0 -> 10.9.0+. I run:

```
$ node -v
v10.4.0
```

Then:

```
$ sudo npm install -g n
```

And I get:

```
$ sudo npm install -g n
Unhandled rejection Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/Users/myuser/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/b0/67'

npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/myuser/.npm/_logs/2019-06-12T19_41_01_814Z-debug.log
```

When I got to `/Users/myuser/.npm/_logs/2019-06-12T19_41_01_814Z-debug.log` I see an empty/blank file.

**What is happening and what is the fix?**

---

#### Update

Here's what I get when I try to clean caches:

```
$ npm cache clean
npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead. On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer, you can use `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.
$ npm cache clean --force
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
npm ERR! path /Users/myuser/.npm/_cacache/content-v2
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall rmdir
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/Users/myuser/.npm/_cacache/content-v2'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/Users/myuser/.npm/_cacache/content-v2']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/Users/myuser/.npm/_cacache/content-v2'
npm ERR!      errno: -13,
npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'rmdir',
npm ERR!      path: '/Users/myuser/.npm/_cacache/content-v2' },
npm ERR!   isOperational: true,
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir \'/Users/myuser/.npm/_cacache/content-v2\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rmdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/myuser/.npm/_cacache/content-v2' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
```

Comment: Can you do a `npm cache clean` then try to reinstall again? if that doesn't work then `npm cache clean --force`?

Comment: Thanks @AritraChakraborty (+1) please see my updates above

Comment: Do your user have permission to install/upgrade on your machine?

Comment: Yeah, this is my personal laptop. Should I try `sudo npm cache clean --force` maybe? What will this do? Are applications on my machine just gonna start crashing?!

Comment: run it with sudo

Comment: Thanks @AritraChakraborty (+1) but that warning messages are scaring me a little bit. What will this command actually do, and what impact could it have on the things presently installed on my machine?

Comment: FWIW this is a [know NPM bug](https://github.com/isaacs/chownr/issues/20) and a fix is presently underway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although a [PR is currently underway](https://github.com/isaacs/chownr/issues/20) the temporary work around is:

Modify **both** the following files the exact same way:

- `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/chownr/chownr.js`; and
- `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/node_modules/chownr/chownr.js`

Modify these files by changing:

```
/* istanbul ignore next */
const LCHOWN = fs.lchown ? 'lchown' : 'chown'
/* istanbul ignore next */
const LCHOWNSYNC = fs.lchownSync ? 'lchownSync' : 'chownSync'
```

To:

```
/* istanbul ignore next */
const LCHOWN = 'chown'
/* istanbul ignore next */
const LCHOWNSYNC = 'chownSync'
```

Then re-run the upgrade and it should succeed.